# Django allauth template integration trouble

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm new to coding, Python and Django, but trying to handle that :)

Decided to learn while trying to make a real project. 
Almost every trouble I get is solvable with the help of Google, but now I'm stucked at one point, and cannot find any information about that.

The thing is that I'm using a template from Themeforest called Jango (he-he :)) It can be find here: [link](http://themehats.com/themes/jango/shop-home-1.html). 
As you can see on that page, it has nice looking 'Sign In' button, and when you click it, sign in form appears.

So my question is how could I integrate that kind of form with allauth app. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation in this [link](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html).
If you create a file with account/login.html name in your template, it can override the one shipped with allauth.

For more information look at: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html

Comment: The thing is that I don't need a separate login page. If you follow the link to template demo, you can see that login form is just a popup window, and not a separate page. So I'm confused about how I can integrate that.